# How to Sort by Count

Tags: list-view, sorting

I am tracking a large list of deals by ID Number. I want to be able to see how many times each ID Number appears in my tracker, if it appears more than once.

I can create a view and view the count next to the ID Number of how many times it is listed in the tracker, but I can't sort this count to show the top counts listed in a single place (preferably at the top).

Is there a way for me to do this?

I am a novice, so please give me detailed help!

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to implement this is to set up grouping on your view.  Expand the "Group by" settings in the view settings page.

[image]

[image]