# I want to sort and count items in a list and sort them from largest to smallest

Tags: list, custom

I have a SharePoint list. It contains data such as:

```
 Name - Topic
 John - Topic1
 Bob - Topic2
 Bob - Topic3
 Bob - Topic4
 John - Topic2
 Dave - Topic1
```

I want my list to be sorted like:

```
 Bob 3
 John 2
 Dave 1
```

Sorted by greatest number of items on top connected with name inputted.

I have tried all methods I can think of including Group By -- With group by, i can't sort from largest number of items.

I feel like a count formula or countif may be the solution...but i can't figure out the correct way of incorporating it.

I am looking for a solution to this without having to go in back end and write code. I am find with implementing script web part if needed, but that's as technical as i'd like to go.

Is this possible without going in back end?

Thanks - i really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried Sorting, Grouping and Total together under views?

Comment: Hi - I have tried this and many variations - all failed to achieve what i want.  Do you have specifics by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
count($Rows[current()/@Title=@Title])
```

if you want to use DVWP follow this link:
http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/20/showing-subtotals-in-a-dvwp-sorted-by-the-subtotals/

or you can try the following:
[How to Sort by Count](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71640/how-to-sort-by-count)

Comment: Hello Supermode -

That formula didn't work.

Do you think there's another approach other than utilizing a DVWP?